# Dynamic javascript div id in nested form

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a nested form, which is loaded by add more button, In the nested form I have radio button. According to the radio button, a javascript function is called to hide or show a div. But for more than two or more form the radio button javascript calls the first div as div id is static. plz help. here the the code.

form.html.erb

```
 <%= f.fields_for :book_chapters  do |book| %>
 <%= render '/publications/book_chapter', :ff => book %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.link_to_add "Add chapter", :book_chapters, :class => "add_category_link"%>
```

_book_chapter.html.erb

```
<%= ff.input :chapter_no %>
<%= ff.input :chapter_title %>
<%= ff.input :description %>
<%= ff.input :pdf, :hint => "Please upload Pdf's Only." %>     
<div class="control-group string optional">
  <label class="string optional control-label">Plan</label>
<div class="controls">
<%= ff.radio_button :plan, "free", :class=>"relat__atu relat__atu_no" %> Free
<%= ff.radio_button :plan, "premium", :class=>"relat__atu relat__atu_yes" %>Premium

<script>
  jQuery(".relat__atu").on("change", function(){
    jQuery("#esatu").toggle($(this).hasClass("relat__atu_yes"));
  })
</script>

<div id="esatu" style="display:none">
  <label for="relat_tipus_atu">
    <%= ff.input :credits %>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="controls">
  <%= ff.link_to_remove "remove", :class => "remove_category" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by looking into nested form gem . Inside nested gem unique Id is generated for each addition dynamically. data-blueprint is parsed and "new_#{association}" is replaced with generated unique ID.In my case relation was like 'publication' has_many 'book_chapters' so my association was book_chapters. I assigned new row with id = "book_chapters" and its replaced by unique Id when new row is added.

Maybe its useful some one else

Answer (score 0):

You can render the partial inside a div like

```
<div class='some_div'>
  <%= render '/publications/book_chapter', :ff => book %>
</div>
```

Change id of your div to class

```
<div class="esatu" style="display:none">
```

And change js to

```
jQuery(".some_div").on("change", ".relat__atu", function() {
  jQuery(".esatu", $(this).parent('.some_div')).toggle($(this).hasClass("relat__atu_yes"));
})
```

Comment: Made few more changes. Can you check now?